# Check if there is at least one value in column C that is bigger then the value in Column B (without Helper Column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | sales_volume | purchase_volume | Check |
| 2 | Product_A | 500 | 400 | yes |
| 3 | Product_B | 600 | 700 |  |
| 4 | Product_C | 300 | 250 |  |
| 5 | Product_D | 800 | 620 |  |
| 6 | Product_E | 100 | 100 |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |

---

In `Cell D2` I want to have a formula that is doing the following:

```
= If there is at least one value in Column C > value in Column B then "yes" else "no"
```

---

I know I could achieve this with a `Helper Column` that subtracts the values from both Columns and then check the Helper Column for values >= 0.

However, I would prefer a solution without a `Helper Column`.

Do you have any idea if this is possible?

Comment: So if you get a result in D2, it says "yes" but could apply to a result somewhere in the column? Or D2 check for row 2, D3 for row 3 etc? If the latter, then yes it is possible.

Comment: It is not related to the row. So the check in Cell D2 could be placed anywhere in the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(SUM(IF(C2:C6>B2:B6, 1, 0))>0, "yes", "no")`
Be warned this is an array formula so might required you to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing the formula instead of just inserting it normally

Comment: As far as I can tell the array-formula is only needed for version before Offic365

Answer (score 0):

If B2 is GREATER than the largest number in the range C2:C6, then "no", else "yes".

Try this formula in cell D2:

```
=IF(B2>MAX(C$2:C$6),"no","yes")
```

you can then drag the formula down to other cells