# Count how many values in Column D are bigger than in Column C based on criteria in Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product | Brand | sales_volume | purchase_volume |
| 2 | Product_A | Brand_A | 500 | 400 |
| 3 | Product_B | Brand_A | 600 | 700 |
| 4 | Product_C | Brand_B | 300 | 250 |
| 5 | Product_D | Brand_B | 800 | 620 |
| 6 | Product_E | Brand_A | 100 | 100 |
| 7 | Product_F | Brand_C | 300 | 400 |

---

With reference to the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290754/check-if-there-is-at-least-one-value-in-column-c-that-is-bigger-then-the-value-i) in `Cell E2` I want to:

```
Count how many values in Column D are bigger than in Column C only for Brand_A
```

---

How do I need to adjust this formula `=SUM(IF(D2:D7>C2:C7;1;0))` to add `Brand_A` as a criteria?

Comment: add it to the logical test in the if().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D7>C2:C7)*(B2:B7="Brand_A"))
```